# Segundo Value não funciona

Tags: javascript, value

Montei esse código para estudos, mas quando executo ele a idade junto com a mensagem não aparece, olhei no console lá fala que o problema esta no segundo value, quando tiro ele aparece: `usuário possuí null anos`.

```js
function enviar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.write("Welcome, ", nome);
  var idade = document.getElementById("idade1").value;
  document.write("<br>O usuário possuí ", idade, " anos");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<TItle>teste Prompt</TItle>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="PROMPT" content="TESTANDO">
<style>
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
  }
  
  .inicio {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
</style>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="inicio container">
    <form>
      <H2>nome</H2>
      <input id="text" type="text">
      <h2>idade</h2>
      <input id="idade1" type="number">
      <button onclick="enviar()">Confirmar</button>

      <script>
      </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no seu `document.write` pois quando realiza a primeira escrita ele muda o `html` então na segunda escrita não vai encontrar o `form` para escrever.
Altere a sua `function` para:

```
function enviar(){
    var nome = document.getElementById("text").value;                 
    var idade = document.getElementById("idade").value;
    document.write("Welcome, ", nome, "<br>O usuário possui ", idade ," anos");
}
```

Outra coisa seu `form` não está corretamente fechado, tenha cuidado nisso pois poderá te atrapalhar bastante.

Comment: Obgd man, ajudou muito, estou começando agr.